# How to test your code on a machine with big-endian architecture?

Tags: c++, c, architecture, solaris, endianness

Both [**ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/) and [**codepad.org**](http://www.codepad.org/) have [**Little-Endian**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) architechtures.

I want to test my code on some machine with **Big-Endian** architechture (for example - Solaris - which I don't have). Is there some easy way that you know about?

Comment: Wouldn't Solaris on an x86 or x86-64 architecture be little-endian too?  And I think SPARC is bi-endian to boot.

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION: I think you are right. It should be. Though I am not sure. lets wait for others to comment.

Comment: Yes, Solaris matches the processor endianness (as does OS X, for that matter).  It's big-endian on SPARC and little-endian on x86/x86-64.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imitate/emulate a big-endian behavior in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337896/imitate-emulate-a-big-endian-behavior-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Googling "big endian online emulator" lead me to [PearPC](http://pearpc.sourceforge.net/). I assume that if you have the patience you can [install Mandrake Linux](http://pearpc.sourceforge.net/installlinux.html), get gcc, and go party.

Comment: Isnt power pc bi-endian? Which means in a linux with could be little endian?

Comment: @AndréPuel: Well, if someone were to bother porting Linux to ppcle, sure.  But what would be the point?  This won't let it run anywhere it couldn't already, will it?

Answer (score 27):

[QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) supports emulating several big-endian architectures.  Note that some architectures support both endiannesses; some (Itanium, ARM) are primarily used as little-endian while others (PowerPC, MIPS) are primarily used as big-endian.

Aurélien Jarno wrote some HOWTOs on installing Debian on an emulated [MIPS](http://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_mips_qemu.php) or [SPARC](http://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_sparc_qemu.php) machine which should be a good start.

Comment: I tried QEMU but only got weird error messages or it just hung up.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Ubuntu, you can download MIPS cross compiler (or any other big-endian architecture that is supported by QEMU, and has a prebuilt cross compiler), and QEMU-user, then compile your code in static linkage, and just run it.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib-mips-linux-gnu gcc-mips-linux-gnu qemu-user
```

and then

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc test.c -o test -static
qemu-mips ./test
```