# Workflow for testing endianess compatibility

Tags: c++, testing, endianness

What is a good workflow for testing code written with support for varying endianess? For example, I can test against my current architecture but what about testing (rather than guessing) that I haven't made a mistake for others?

Only BE and LE are of concern but I understand that there are some mixed endian systems out there. Is there a simple way to automate tests against these architectures?

My environment is Windows (little endian) so Bochs isn't a good solution. Currently looking at installing a BSD on QEMU.

Comment: As I could see, installing QEMU and testing for different arch-s is a good variant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337896/imitate-emulate-a-big-endian-behavior-in-c

Answer (score 0):

As I could see, [installing QEMU and testing for different architectures is a good variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337896/imitate-emulate-a-big-endian-behavior-in-c).

You could test your code both with *big-endian*, with *little-endian* and with *bi-endian* architectures. Write the script, that starts specific OS's in [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Manual) , compile your code under them and execute tests.

To make the integration process uniform, [there's a broad choice of Debian images for different architectures](https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/).
You could start Debian in console mode without `X`. Your code could be downloaded *operando* from the server each time due to [QEMU supports network](http://wiki.qemu.org/Manual).