# Testing big endian without real big endian processor

Tags: c, endianness

I want to test my c code for big endian on Windows (On x86-64). How can we do this?

Comment: @Steve with which software?

Comment: vmware, virtual box and many more...

Comment: @Steve Are they support big endian processor emulation?

Comment: um...not 100% sure.. you have to google it yourself

Comment: possible duplicate of [Imitate/emulate a big-endian behavior in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337896/imitate-emulate-a-big-endian-behavior-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test your code on a machine with big-endian architecture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839087/how-to-test-your-code-on-a-machine-with-big-endian-architecture)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have any actual big-endian hardware to hand, your best bet is to use a virtual machine such as [QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU#Features) to emulate a big-endian architecture such as [SPARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC) or [PowerPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC).

You'll then need to install a suitable operating system on your VM - perhaps [Debian](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/weekly-builds/) would suit your needs.